# django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0004_auto_20200309_0721 dependencies reference nonexistent

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-3.0

I created a project with Django3 and i'm using sqlite3 database. When i try to migrate the project initiallly it raising the error like this :

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0004_auto_20200309_0721 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('main', '0001_initial')

although there is no any migration dependencies before.
I search for this error on google but nothing worked for me . 
How can i solve this issue ?
I will be glad if i get solution of this.